# Why I can't access the memory directly?

Tags: gdb

```
(gdb) p it
$2 = (item *) 0x6
(gdb) p *it
$3 = {next = 0x0, prev = 0x0, h_next = 0x0, time = 0, exptime = 0, nbytes = 7, refcount = 1, nsuffix = 6 '\006', it_flags = 2 '\002', slabs_clsid = 1 '\001', nkey = 6 '\006', 
  end = 0x7f0890b6e040}
(gdb) p *0x6
Cannot access memory at address 0x6
```

Isn't `p *it` and `p *0x6` the same thing here??

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are on an embedded target that has real memory mapped at address 0, the value of `it` == `0x6` is *bogus* (usually result of a null pointer dereference).

The fact that `gdb` prints `*it` probably means there is a bug in `gdb`, but it's hard to say. Unfortunately you didn't say which version of GDB, and what OS, you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The gdb 'p' command can only be used for printing variables value.
If you want to inspect memory have a look [there](http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html#Memory)